# Pygame Image Rotation

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a simple program top down driving simulator with Python and Pygame.  The driving part is working fine; the up key moves the car and the right and left keys steer it.  The problem is in the rotation of the image; it moves all over the place (run the code to see it).  I think it is because when the image rotates the size is changed (since it has to be a rectangle).  When the resolution changes, so does the location.  If anyone knows a way around this I would really appreciate it.
car.png --> [image]

```
import pygame, math
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 500))
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
pygame.display.set_caption('Car Driving')

def main():
    r = 0
    car = pygame.image.load('images/car.png')

    while True:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        r += 3

        screen.fill((40,40,40))
        screen.blit(pygame.transform.rotate(car, r), (200, 100))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(40)


main()
```

Comment: your question really shouldn't be set up to force us to run your code. Even if we wanted to we don't have your car.png image. Just show the important parts of the code and explain your problem

Comment: You need to have the image (or any image) for the problem to actually happen.  Running the code is a lot easier than me explaining the problem.  But i'll simplify it anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From PYgame docs:

> Unless rotating by 90 degree increments, the image will be padded larger to hold the new size.

That means that you get a new Rect object. There's no info in the docs, but I think the original image will be on the center on the new Rect.
That would mean that If you place the new Rect's position to the needed position, you'll get the expected result.

```python
center=(100,200) #Store pos by center

#In loop:
rCar=pygame.transform.rotate(car,r) #Do the rotation
size=rCar.get_size() #Store size
hSize=[n/2 for n in size] #Half the size
pos=(center[0]-hSize[0],center[1]-hSize[1])  #Substract half the size
#from the center
screen.blit(rCar,pos) #Draw
```

Let me explain:

[image]

I hope it helped you.